# Alter columns from selected result table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here the things,I want to join  table '`responsibilities`' with fields `Name, Direct, Supervise`:

```
Name | Direct | Supervise
 ABC    2        4
```

and table 'positions' with positionCode, positionID:

```
positionCode | positionID
   HR/HRM         2
   HR/MN          4
```

The selected result table will be some thing like this.

```
Name | Direct | Supervise
 ABC   HR/HRM    HR/MN
```

The '`Direct`' and '`Supervise`' column should be `positionCode` from 'positions' table. Is there an all-in-one query to output this result? Or I have to query 2 times ?

Comment: You join the table twice with different names and different columns and you will get the result easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can join `responsibilities` twice to the `positions` table:

```
SELECT r.Name,
       COALESCE(p1.positionCode, 'Direct is N/A') AS Direct,
       COALESCE(p2.positionCode, 'Supervise is N/A') AS Supervise
FROM responsibilities r
LEFT JOIN positions p1
    ON r.Direct = p1.positionID
LEFT JOIN positions p2
    ON r.Supervise = p2.positionID
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: In responsibilities table there is no positionCode column so will get Unknown column 'r.positionCode' in 'field list' error

Comment: The code works fine for me if i add p1, p2 's position Code into selection. Anyway, thanks for show me the light

Comment: @QuangAnhChu I wrapped the code column selections with `COALESCE()` in the event that a given responsibility doesn't have any positions available.  In this case, the alternative message (e.g. `Direct is N/A`) would be shown to the user.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An arrow hit 2 targets, i'm looking for that too, thanks mate for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

Try this Query,

```
SELECT r.Name,
       p1.positionCode AS Direct,
       p2.positionCode AS Supervise
FROM responsibilities r
LEFT JOIN positions p1
    ON r.Direct = p1.positionID
LEFT JOIN positions p2
    ON r.Supervise = p2.positionID
```

Output: [SEE SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbebf/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try following Query, It should work

```
select R.Name,(select P.positionCode where R.Direct=P.positionID) as 
Direct,(select P.positionCode where R.Supervise=P.positionID) as 
Supervise from Responsibilites R, Positions P;
```

Comment: A regular join would look a lot better than subqueries

Answer (score 0):

check out this SQL Fiddle for proof that this query works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13845c/4/0

Basically, the query looks as follows:

```
SELECT r.Name, p1.positionCode As Direct, p2.positionCode as Supervise
FROM responsibilities r 
LEFT JOIN positions p1 ON r.Direct = p1.positionID
LEFT JOIN positions p2 ON r.Supervise = p2.positionID
```